# jQuery to Vanilla JS - querySelector issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm going through some code and working to change all of the jQuery to `vanilla JS`. However there is one section and I keep getting an error in my console that says either:

> TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).toggle is not a function pr
>   TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...) is null

Below is my code, the top part you can see is where I am trying to change the jquery to `vanilla js` (I have commented out the jquery) :

```
console.log(shipmentNumbers);
            for (let i = 0; i < shipmentNumbers.length; i += 1) {
                let sNumber = shipmentNumbers[i];

                function getHistory(event) {
                    console.log(event);
                    document.querySelectorAll('#shipment' + sNumber + 'tr.show-history' + sNumber).toggle();
                    // $('#shipment' + sNumber + ' tr.show-history' + sNumber).toggle();
                    document.getElementsByClassName('overlay-line' + sNumber).style.display = 'table-row';
                    // $('.overlay-line' + sNumber).css({
                    //  "display": "table-row"
                    // });
                    if (flag == false) {
                        let shipmentNumber = event.currentTarget.id.replace('status', '');
                        console.log('shipmentNumber=', shipmentNumber);
                        callHistoryApi(clientId, shipmentNumber);
                        $(this).find('.expand' + sNumber).html("&#9660;");
                        flag = true;
                    } else {
                        $(this).find('.expand' + sNumber).html("&#9658;");
                        $('.overlay-line' + sNumber).css({
                            "display": "none"
                        });
                        flag = false;
                    }
                }
```

Can someone explain why this isn't working, and how I can get it working using `vanilla js`?

Comment: `toggle` is not available in native JavaScript, you need to write a function to add or remove the class yourself!

Comment: The value returned from `querySelectorAll` doesn't have a `toggle()` method. `.toggle()` is a jQuery feature.

Comment: just noting that you forgot a space in the 'tr.show-history' string

Comment: Also you can't simply operate on a set of element in native JS like jQuery does here `document.getElementsByClassName('overlay-line' + sNumber).style` that .style will also produce an error, you need to loop through all returned elements.

Comment: And, in your case, i guess that you could use querySelector (one element is in quesion, right?), rather than querySelectorAll (which returns elements list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that writing these two functions can really help when moving from jQuery to native JS.

```
function domEach(selector, handler, context) {
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector), handler, context);
}

// If you get a TypeError "Array.from" is not a function, use the polyfill
// found on MPN.
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from
```

This gets you around issues where you relied on implicit loops that jQuery uses.

```
// Instead of these:

document.querySelectorAll('#shipment' + sNumber + 'tr.show-history' + sNumber).toggle();
document.getElementsByClassName('overlay-line' + sNumber).style.display = 'table-row';

// Use these:

domEach('#shipment' + sNumber + 'tr.show-history' + sNumber, function (tr) {

    tr.style.display = tr.style.display === "none"
        ? ""
        : "none";

});

domEach('.overlay-line' + sNumber, function (el) {
    el.style.display = 'table-row';
});
```

For a list of techniques to use instead of the jQuery functions, you can check [You Might Not Need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

**Edit: more information about the code above**

jQuery uses implicit loops. That is, when you do this:

```
$("#one").addClass("two");
```

jQuery does this behind the scenes:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#one");
var i = 0;
var il = elements.length;
while (i < il) {
    elements[i].classList.add("two");
    i += 1;
}
```

This leads to some confusion when going from jQuery to vanilla JavaScript since you have to manually loop over the results of `querySelectorAll`.

`Array.from` will loop over an array or array-like structure. `querySelectorAll` will return a `NodeList` - this is an array-like structure (it has numerical indicies and a `length` property). The `domEach` function allows us to pass a CSS selector to the function and will loop over the results of finding matching elements.

The `? :` syntax is called a **ternary operator**. It's a short-cut for `if ... else`.

```
// Ternary operator
tr.style.display = tr.style.display === "none"
    ? ""
    : "none";

// Equivalent if/else statements
if (tr.style.display === "none") {
    tr.style.display = "";
} else {
    tr.style.display = "none";
}
```

I hope that helps clarify things.

Comment: MDN has a [polyfill for Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) that accurately imitates its behavior.

Comment: would you mind explaining in laymens terms what exactly is happening here? sorry, i am very much a beginner and not quite sure what's happening in those first two functions, and i haven't come across the ?"" :"none" syntax before. thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @JLRishe - it boils down to a wrapper for `Array.prototype.map` - so long as that functiona hasn't been modified, it's all you need for an `Array.from` polyfill

Comment: @KatherineMichelle - I've added some details, I hope that helps

Comment: @xander - I think you're thinking of [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) instead of [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/). Although in fairness, jQuery's toggle can handle animations which my version cannot

Comment: @JamesLong this is the best answer i've ever recieved on here, thank you so much for answering my questions and for explaining everything so clearly

Comment: @KatherineMichelle - glad to be helpful :)

Comment: @JamesLong Calling off to `map` is a close facsimile, but there are subtle differences. Why not just use an accurate polyfill?

Comment: @JLRishe - speed and laziness. You're right, `Array.from` doesn't need a function as you can just pass a single argument. That's the only real difference between them, though. I'll update the answer

Comment: Other differences are its `.length` property and its behavior when called on something other than `Array` (e.g. `MyArrayLikeType.from = Array.from; var arrayLikeInstance = MyArrayLikeType.from(someOtherArrayLikeThing);`) Again, subtle differences and not something that people would typically run into, but I think that might be all the more reason to use a tried and tested polyfill that thoroughly matches the standard.

Comment: @JLRishe - I never knew about that. That seems so ... alright, proper polyfill - answer updated

Answer (score -1):

You must add check in whenever you do this, as .querySelctor/All() is going to return "null" if no elements are found.

```
var myCollection = document.querySelectorAll("selector");
if (myCollection.length > 0){
   Array.prototype.forEach.call(myCollenction, function(element){
      if(typeof element.toggle === "function"){
         element.toggle();
      }
   })
}
```

More or less this will help you achieve your goal. However if you don't have method "toggle" defined on your elements - nothing will happen. :)

Comment: Under what situation would the elements have a `toggle` method? And I don't think that `querySelectorAll()` should ever return `null`. At least, it doesn't in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: If you decorate your HTML elements with methods on the prototype they will have one. I am confused by your remark. Re null value, you are right, by definition it returns empty node list.

Comment: OP's use of `toggle` was clearly a mistaken attempt to use a jQuery feature without jQuery. Her elements don't have `toggle` on their prototype. And anyone modifying DOM elements' prototypes in this day and age is looking for trouble.

Comment: In what way do any of those modify DOM prototypes?

Comment: All the polyfills you load in order to support whatever are extending the native interfaces. I don't want to get into this discussion in "this day and age", but extending native prototypes with custom methods has it's use cases and is one of the biggest advantages of the language.

Comment: Polyfills are a workaround for supporting new standards in environments that don't implement those standards, and most polyfills are used on well-behaved built-in types (like `Array` and `Object`), not host objects (like the DOM). Prototype.js extensively modified the DOM to add custom features and there is a [section on its Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_JavaScript_Framework#Problems) that discusses why this was a bad idea and that they plan to release a very different version 2.0 that doesn't modify the DOM, at the expense of backward compatibility with 1.x.

Comment: At any rate, your answer mistakenly assumes that OP is working with a modified DOM that has `.toggle()` methods on its elements, which it doesn't. So your code doesn't provide a solution to her issue.

Comment: Sadly you said nothing of substance, and vaguely linking to some article in Wiki with the extreme case of Proto.js... come on, you've got to be better than that. I acknowledged that: "However if you don't have method "toggle" defined on your elements - nothing will happen. :)" in my answer. If there was interest in pursuing this direction from OP I was going to extend it. Nevertheless I enjoyed teasing your spiteful being - you were busy with me instead of someone else. That's a good deed :)

Comment: I'm still curious to hear how Angular, React, or Vue modify the DOM prototypes.

Comment: All the Polyfills do. Simple examples: DOM traversing. element.closest("..."). I am starting to think you have no clue how DOM trees are traversed and updated.

Comment: I can't find any evidence of Angular, React, or Vue polyfilling `.closest`, which isn't even standardized yet. _"I am starting to think you have no clue how DOM trees are traversed and updated."_ I can understand your confusion, given that you apparently think traversing and updating DOM trees involves tacking unstandardized methods onto the DOM prototypes.

Comment: Lol :) Just gave you an example, you are free to extrapolate whatever you want out of it. DOM traversing takes many forms. Writing ESNext and using latest APIs requires polyfills that are doing just that. The same is with the polyfills for Map.